# Drupal MultiSite, Multiple Sites or Organic Groups

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, organic-groups

I am using Drupal for a project but am not sure on the best way to implement the following.

I have one main site with it's own look and feel.
I want another site with certain members of the main site in it. It should have it's own look and feel. It should have both public and private conent.

What out of the folling would you do.

Use MultiSite and share the users table
Use Mutliple Sites and find a way of linking the users.
Use one site and use Organic groups.

Kind Regards

Rupert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like organic groups is the most natural fit to your needs, as it is designed to do what you want. The other options are workarounds to do roughly what you want.

Comment: So just to confirm you can have a group with public(anomous and non group members) and private(group memembers only) content?

Comment: @Jeremy French: your db is down.

Answer (score 1):

OG is definitely the place to start. If it doesn't work, you might also try the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module. It is geared around creating multiple Drupal sites on top of a single Drupal instance. It is more extreme separation than Organic Groups, but it is a smaller user base than OG, which might mean slower bugfixes/etc.

Multisite with a shared user table is a maintenance complexity you probably don't need.

Answer (score 1):

One easy part of the solution would be to install [drupal cas](http://drupal.org/project/cas) plugin to share the session and users between two instances of drupal.

We did it to isolate the development activities on websites. This way helping us a lot by avoiding collateral bugs.